# How to style a custom "control" that uses the css styles from input control

Tags: html, css

I know you can obviously style all your inputs/controls to share the same CSS, but my question is whether it's possible to get/use styles from the user agent style sheet to create custom inputs that share the look of the others.

For example,

```
.control > input {border:0;}

<div class="control">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Is there any way that you could style the outer div (in terms of border when one of the controls has focus) based on the user agent styling for a text input for example?

One clear issue is that focus pseudo class wouldn't be usable
e.g.

```
<div class="control focused">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: You could read the currently applied style using `getComputedStyle` …

Comment: you know that would actually work i think.  I'm doing it within an AngularJS directive, so could easily render an invisible input element then get the agent specific css for the input `window.getComputedStyle(myInputEl,"focus")` - then get the border css properties and apply them to container element. thanks!